# Why can I only create a function alias using the type auto?

Tags: c++, alias, auto

I have the following static function defined in the utilities namespace.

```
class InvalidDecimalPlace {};

namespace utilities
{
    double static RoundToNthDecimalPlace(double number, int decimalPlace)
    {
        if (decimalPlace < 0 )
            throw InvalidDecimalPlace();
        else if (decimalPlace == 0)
            return static_cast<int>(number);

        int powerUp = std::pow(10, decimalPlace);
        number *= powerUp;
        int numberWithoutDecimals = static_cast<int>(number);
        return numberWithoutDecimals / static_cast<double>(powerUp);

    }
};
```

In another file I want to alias this function so I don't need to qualify it with the scope resolution operator. Somebody told me to do the following:

```
auto& RoundToNDecimalPlace = utilities::RoundToNthDecimalPlace;
// Or the following, const auto RoundToNDecimalPlace = utilities::RoundToNthDecimalPlace;
```

I noticed that this only works with `auto` though. Why is this the case? For instance, why doesn't the following work?

```
double& RoundToNDecimalPlace = utilities::RoundToNthDecimalPlace;
```

Comment: The type of `utilities::RoundToNthDecimalPlace` is not `double`, it's `double(double, int)`

Comment: Any reason you can't just write `using utilities::RoundToNthDecimalPlace;` ?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik No reason, just trying to learn as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Since `utilities::RoundToNthDecimalPlace` is a function, its type is

```
double (double, int);
```

This is the type of a function taking in a double and returning an int. Notice that this isn’t the same as type double, so you can’t bind a reference of type `double&` to it.

When you use `auto&`, C++ is properly inferring the type of the variable to be

```
double (&) (double, int)
```

which is a reference to a function taking in a double and an int that then returns a double.

That being said, there’s no need to use a reference variable here. If you want to be able to access that one function more concisely, just say

```
using utilities::RoundToNthDecimalPlace;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the function is not `double`, it's `double (&) (double, int)` which is, I think, what you end up with when you use `auto`. But the name of a function decays into a pointer, so the "usual" approach (inherited from C) would be to create a pointer to that function, like this:

```
double (*fn)(double, int) = utilities::RoundToNthDecimalPlace;
```

Now you can use `find just like you'd use the original function:

```
double result = fn(1.0, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why can I only create a function alias using the type auto?

What you've declared with `auto&` is a reference to function. The commented `auto` would define a pointer to function instead.

`double` is not a function (instead, it is an object type), so it is the wrong type to use for referring to a function. The correct type of `utilities::RoundToNthDecimalPlace` is `double (double, int)`. So the equivalent declaration to `auto` would be:

```
double (*RoundToNDecimalPlace)(double, int) = utilities::RoundToNthDecimalPlace;
```

However for clarity, I recommend a type alias:

```
using RoundingFunction = double (double, int);
RoundingFunction* RoundToNDecimalPlace = utilities::RoundToNthDecimalPlace;
```

So in conclusion: No, you don't need to use `auto`, but you cannot use a wrong type either.